# asp.net mvc sitemap that adjusts for screen size so menus are not off the screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

When navigating windows menus if the submenu will be off screen, the submenu is offset up or down to keep it on screen?

We are using this one, that is old... it does not try to keep the maps onscreen...

```
>    <add name="MvcSiteMap"
> type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider"
> scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="false"
> treatAttributesAsRouteValues="true" siteMapFile="~/Web.Sitemap"
> securityTrimmingEnabled="true" cacheDuration="10" />
```

Is there a new better implementation that has this behavior?

One that uses the same sitemap formatting would be extra awesome...

Thanks,

Eric-

Answer (score 0):

The menu template can be edited to get whatever HTML output you want, and then you can use CSS to control the visual aspect. It's no different than modifying any other MVC view.

You can edit the template by modifying the /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MenuHelperModel.cshtml file (or MenuHelperModel.aspx if you are not using razor). If you don't have the file in your project, you can get the contents of the [Razor](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Html/DisplayTemplates/MenuHelperModel.cshtml) and [ASPX](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Web/Html/DisplayTemplates/MenuHelperModel.ascx) files and add them to your project manually.

Also, it looks like you have a very old version - here is the [upgrade documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Upgrading-from-v3-to-v4) to version 4.0.